# Symfony2 architecture

Tags: php, symfony, architecture

I am developing an app with Symfony2 that has 3 main parts called frontoffice, backoffice, admin. I was thinking to create three separate bundles: FrontOfficeBundle, BackOfficeBundle, AdminBundle but Symfony's docs says, each bundle should not have any relation with each other. Entity is already a shared property and probably some models. I could create a SharedBundle but it does not make sense. I remember when I created an app 2 years go when I had like 15 bundles and all connected each other and I know from experience that it's a nightmare.

Should I have just one bundle AppBundle and logic split in the folders, eg. Controller/Admin; Controller/FrontOffice, Controller/BackOffice?

What's the best approach?

Comment: Yes, you should have only one AppBundle for your application logic.

Comment: You had better read best practices first.
http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/creating-the-project.html

Comment: Those **best practices** advertise the service locator anti-pattern. This means your controller has access to the whole service container instead of only what it really needs. If you use Dependency Injection instead you get better testability and as a bonus the dependencies of a given controller are visible in its constructor.

Answer (score 1):

It's all about [**SRP**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) and [**DRY**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)

It doesn't hurt to create a bundle, so make a separate bundle for stuff you need in multiple bundles, e.g. I tend to create an EntityBundle which contains entities and their repositories (as service).

Of course you can just use a single AppBundle too but **please** don't put your logic into the controllers -> create reusable *services*! Inject the services you need into your controller (which should themselves be services too).

[Alternatives to base Controller Methods](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/service.html#alternatives-to-base-controller-methods)

Answer (score 0):

No such thing as best approach.

However, instead of grouping by class type (Controller,Command,Form,Templates) within a directory, I like to create a single "component" directory for each request action.  So I would have

```
Action
  FrontOffice
  BackOffics
  Admin
    User
      UserController.php
      UserFormType.php
      UserTemplate.html.twig
```

Grouping files in this fashion really cuts down on figuring out where the various files live.  Is it the "best" approach? Nope.  But it works for me.